# #1062 - Duplicate entry KEY PRIMARY

Tags: phpmyadmin

This is what I wanna insert, but it shows this error

```sql
INSERT INTO item(ITEM_ID,ITEM_NAME,ITEM_PRICE,CATEGORIES_ID,RESTAURANT_ID)VALUES("IT0001","WHITE TOAST","1.70","C001","RES001")
MySQL said: Documentation

#1062 - Duplicate entry 'IT0001' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

```sql
INSERT INTO item(ITEM_ID,ITEM_NAME,ITEM_PRICE,CATEGORIES_ID,RESTAURANT_ID)VALUES("IT0001","WHITE TOAST","1.70","C001","RES001");
INSERT INTO item(ITEM_ID,ITEM_NAME,ITEM_PRICE,CATEGORIES_ID,RESTAURANT_ID)VALUES("IT0008","CHOCOLATE ICECREAM","6.70","C005","RES003");
INSERT INTO item(ITEM_ID,ITEM_NAME,ITEM_PRICE,CATEGORIES_ID,RESTAURANT_ID)VALUES("IT0003","CHILI CON CARNE","8.250","C004","RES006");
INSERT INTO item(ITEM_ID,ITEM_NAME,ITEM_PRICE,CATEGORIES_ID,RESTAURANT_ID)VALUES("IT0004","NAPOLITANA","6,10","C009","RES010");
INSERT INTO item(ITEM_ID,ITEM_NAME,ITEM_PRICE,CATEGORIES_ID,RESTAURANT_ID)VALUES("IT0005","BLT PANINNI","3,95","C010","RES009");
INSERT INTO item(ITEM_ID,ITEM_NAME,ITEM_PRICE,CATEGORIES_ID,RESTAURANT_ID)VALUES("IT0006","MINI BURGUER","4.20","C007","RES008");
INSERT INTO item(ITEM_ID,ITEM_NAME,ITEM_PRICE,CATEGORIES_ID,RESTAURANT_ID)VALUES("IT0007","OREO MILKSHAKE","3.40","C006","RES004");
INSERT INTO item(ITEM_ID,ITEM_NAME,ITEM_PRICE,CATEGORIES_ID,RESTAURANT_ID)VALUES("IT0002","CHOCOLATE ICECREAM","4.70","C005","RES001");
INSERT INTO item(ITEM_ID,ITEM_NAME,ITEM_PRICE,CATEGORIES_ID,RESTAURANT_ID)VALUES("IT0009","FRIED EGG","1.60","C001","RES008");
INSERT INTO item(ITEM_ID,ITEM_NAME,ITEM_PRICE,CATEGORIES_ID,RESTAURANT_ID)VALUES("IT0010","CHEESE AND TOMATO","3.70","C010","RES002");
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if there is already a record in the the db using that key?

Comment: yes, but I need that record to be repeated, do you know how can I do it ?

Comment: The whole point of a primary key is that it is unique-- the DB is correctly doing its job by preventing you from inserting a duplicate entry?  What are your requirements that you would need to repeat it?  This feels like a potential [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Also, for what it's worth, you might consider adding a [tag:mysql] tag, as this would seem to me to have much more to do w/ MySQL than MyPHPAdmin...